# How to create a polyfill for spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polyfills

I was trying to create a polyfill for the spread operator. My objective is to create something similar to spread operator where instead of triple dots I can use triple @@@ symbols.

For example, in ES6

```
function sum(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(sum(...numbers));
// expected output: 6
```

I was trying to implement similar functionalities

```
// Instead of triple dots, it should be triple @
console.log(sum(@@@numbers));
// expected output should be 6
```

I expect the output of `console.log(sum(@@@numbers));` to be `6`.

Comment: It's impossible, because what you're doing violates Javascript syntax, and syntax is not polyfillable. Transpileable, sure, but not polyfillable.

Comment: so any workaround ??

Comment: No - like I said, it's impossible

Comment: You can of course just write `sum.apply(null, numbers)`, but you cannot introduce your own syntax.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, another way of doing is to use apply. But I was searching for a way to define the syntax.

Comment: @SaswatArabinda There is no way to define custom syntax in JavaScript. You need to use a transpiler that compiles your custom syntax to working code - and of course then you should just use a usual transpiler that compiles the real spread syntax into legacy code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response :)

Answer (score 9):

You [cannot create a polyfill for spread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4922#issuecomment-264134927) operator.

The proper way to deal with such backward compatibility issues is to write your code in ES6, and use [transpiler](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them) like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert it to ES5 automatically.