# Alternative to array spread syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5, spread-syntax

So I'm working with an old codebase that uses ES5 JavaScript, this means I cannot spread arrays

```js
var listOfItems = [ ['item1', 'test', '1'], ['item2', 'test2', '2'] ];

var docDefinition = 
{
  style: 'piecesTable',
  table: {
    widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
    body: [
      [
        {text: 'Reference', style: 'tableHeader'}, 
        {text: 'Alias', style: 'tableHeader'},
        {text: 'Type', style: 'tableHeader'},
      ],
      ...listOfItems
    ]
  }
};
```

How can I spread `listOfItems` without using spread syntax as seen above `...listOfItems`?

The listOfItems should be spread out to two separate arrays so essentially the result should be:

```js
var docDefinition = 
{
  style: 'piecesTable',
  table: {
    widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
    body: [
      [
        {text: 'Reference', style: 'tableHeader'}, 
        {text: 'Alias', style: 'tableHeader'},
        {text: 'Type', style: 'tableHeader'},
      ],
      ['item1', 'test', '1'],
      ['item2', 'test2', '2']
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Is the `listOfItems` going to be spread as two arrays without any extra keys?

Comment: @CVerica yes, listOfItems should be spread out as two sperate arrays ['item1', 'test', '1'] and ['item2', 'test2', '2']

Comment: Is "concat" not what you want?

Comment: @DaveNewton how do I use it in this context? It should spread it into two separate arrays: ['item1', 'test', '1'] and ['item2', 'test2', '2']

Comment: I mean how about after the `docDefinition` definition, you do something like `listOfItems.forEach((item) => {docDefinition.table.body.push(item)}` ?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks @CVerica

Comment: Glad I could help. It also looks like `concat()` that everyone is suggesting works as well, and may look a little cleaner. Good luck!

Comment: @CVerica in the question it is said that OP is using ES5. Your answer includes `(item) => {docDefinition.table.body.push(item)}`  which is an arrow function. Wasn't it introduced in ES6 ?

Comment: @MathewsSunny You are correct. `forEach` is es5, but the arrow function is not. So it would be `listOfItems.forEach(function (item) { docDefinition.table.body.push(item)})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `concat()` to merge into your body array

```js
     var listOfItems = [ ['item1', 'test', '1'], ['item2', 'test2', '2'] ];

      var docDefinition = 
      {
        style: 'piecesTable',
        table: {
          widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
          body: [
            [
              {text: 'Reference', style: 'tableHeader'}, 
              {text: 'Alias', style: 'tableHeader'},
              {text: 'Type', style: 'tableHeader'},
            ],
            
          ].concat(listOfItems)
        }
      };
      
      console.log(docDefinition)
```

Comment: This worked,  I completely forgot about it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatives to spread syntax, seems like we have several options. But do we really have? Well it depends on the situation - lets focus on `concat` and `push`

### concat

Pretty straight forward and a clean way as many suggests. The `concat` method **merges the two array and returns the new array**, so it returns a single array with all the elements, more like using spread. It won't affect the existing arrays since it returns new array, thus we can use it very easily. Let us see that in action:

```js
var listOfItems = [ ['item1', 'test', '1'], ['item2', 'test2', '2'] ];

var docDefinition = 
{
  style: 'piecesTable',
  table: {
    widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
    body: [
      [
        {text: 'Reference', style: 'tableHeader'}, 
        {text: 'Alias', style: 'tableHeader'},
        {text: 'Type', style: 'tableHeader'},
      ],

    ].concat(listOfItems)
  }
};

console.log(docDefinition)
```

### push

The `push` method unlike `concat` would **add new items to the end of the array**, so it mutates our base array to add new elements. The method would update the length of the array and will return the new length. In our case `listOfItems` is an array of arrays, not just array of elements, if we directly apply push it will push the array of arrays, that might be desirable in some situation but may not be in some other. Lets take a look at that :

```js
var listOfItems = [ ['item1', 'test', '1'], ['item2', 'test2', '2'] ];

var docDefinition = 
{
  style: 'piecesTable',
  table: {
    widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
    body: [
      [
        {text: 'Reference', style: 'tableHeader'}, 
        {text: 'Alias', style: 'tableHeader'},
        {text: 'Type', style: 'tableHeader'},
      ],

    ],
  }
};

docDefinition.table.body.push(listOfItems);
console.log(docDefinition)
```

Here as we can see entire array is appended, still if we wanna remove that we could use the `flat` method to remove the sub-arrays to a depth, but it might affect code readability.

Instead, we could push array elements to the destination array by using `forEach` (or some other array traversal method) and push each items to the destination array. Here also the original array is mutated:

```js
var listOfItems = [ ['item1', 'test', '1'], ['item2', 'test2', '2'] ];

var docDefinition = 
{
  style: 'piecesTable',
  table: {
    widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
    body: [
      [
        {text: 'Reference', style: 'tableHeader'}, 
        {text: 'Alias', style: 'tableHeader'},
        {text: 'Type', style: 'tableHeader'},
      ],

    ],
  }
};

listOfItems.forEach(function(item){docDefinition.table.body.push(item)});
console.log(docDefinition)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `concat()`:

```js
const listOfItems = [ ['item1', 'test', '1'], ['item2', 'test2', '2'] ];

const docDefinition = {
  style: 'piecesTable',
  table: {
  widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
  body: [
    [
      {text: 'Reference', style: 'tableHeader'}, 
      {text: 'Alias', style: 'tableHeader'},
      {text: 'Type', style: 'tableHeader'},
    ]
  ].concat(listOfItems)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to add an item to the front of a list, you can always use [`Array.prototype.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), and for the back there's always [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), or even [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). In general, though [there is no polyfill for the spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092116/how-to-create-a-polyfill-for-spread-operator), there are alternative ways of inserting items into arrays at different indices that you can use instead.